# Android APK signed by different vendors

Tags: android, apk, signature

we are developing a mobile application for one of our clients, and the client currently has an app version on Google's Play Store.

The current app has been developed by an external vendor A, so our client has been uploading the apps with his signature.

Now, we want to go on production with the new app developed by us (We are the vendor B).

The client has given us the keystore file used for signing, the key alias and the password, so we are able to generate an APK with the same package name (com.myclient.myapp). We are signing with V1 (The same way the old app has been signed).

The problem starts when we try to update from the old app to the new one. In an Android device, we install old app, and then we try to update to the new one. Android does not allow us to install the new signed APK because understands that the signatures of both apps seems to be different.

We need help on this topic. Can you please help? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: are you actually signing it properly?

Comment: have to changed any package name either you or else your vendor after placing into playstore(first version)

Comment: and the older app have you installed from playstore only ??

Comment: Was "App signing by Google Play" used for the old app?

Comment: Signature has been performed without any issue, the issue is after, when installing the new app over the old app. Both apps use the same package name. the idea is to update the old app (developed by first vendor) with the new one (Developed by us). I've asked to the client to confirm if the old app has been signed with Google Play signature. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. The package name's should not be matched with the earlier vendor with your changes.
2. Check the gradle versions before generate the signed APK and upload to playstore.
3. Check in the manifest the version name and version code are updating.
4. While generating the signed APK check the check boxes of all with signed full APK.

Comment: Thanks, the idea is using the same package so we can update from the old app to the new one in all devices. So package name must be maintained.

I will check points 2,3 and 4 and update this thread.

Answer (score 0):

"App signing by Google Play" is a two step process. You sign the APK with an upload key and then Google checks this signature and resigns the APK with another key.

If this was used for the old App you will not be able to upgrade an App downloaded from the store with one that was locally signed because the signature key is different.

It will however work if you upload the new App to the Play Store.